# std::for_each on container of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, foreach, hashset

In some class I have a `hash_set` of pointers:

```
std::hash_set<GameObject*> gameObjects;
```

I wish to iterate through all of them and call update. With iterators this would be like this:

```
for(std::hash_set<GameObject*>::iterator it = gameObjects.begin(), it_end = gameObjects.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
{
(*it)->update();
}
```

This is too much code; I want to use `std::for_each`.

If I had just `hash_set<GameObject>`, this would look like this:

```
std::for_each(gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&GameObject::update));
```

or, if update was expecting a parameter,

```
std::for_each(gameObjects.begin(), gameObject.end(), std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun_ref(&GameObject::update), deltaTime));
```

How would these both expressions look for the `hash_set` of pointers?

I am using MS VisualStudio 2010.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? How much of C++11 is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same code you have, but use `mem_fun` instead of `mem_fun_ref`

```
std::for_each(gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(),
    std::mem_fun(&GameObject::update));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have a compiler which supports lambdas (C++11), you could use

```
std::for_each(gameObjects.begin(), gameObjects.end(), [=](GameObject* o) {o->update(deltaTime);});
```

Using lambdas is a good option for many STL algorithms, but, as @phresnel points out, the range-based for loop (also C++11) is more concise in this case:

```
for (auto o : gameObjects)
    o->update(deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `std::for_each`, if your compiler and policy allows for it, you can use C++' *range based for*:

```
for (auto p : gameObjects) p->update();
```

---

<sub>This feature was added with C++11, which is the current C++ standard. Not all compiler(-versions) may support it yet.</sub>